# php image file upload fails on some images

Tags: php, image

I am using the ImageManipulator.php library from here: https://gist.github.com/philBrown/880506

When uploading some images, I get the following error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Image file C:\inetpub\wwwroot is not readable' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\libraries\image-library.php:62 Stack trace: #0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\images\edit-image.php(55): ImageManipulator->setImageFile('C:\inetpub\wwwr...') #1 .{main} thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\libraries\image-library.php on line 62`

The function referenced is:

```
if (!(is_readable($file) && is_file($file))) {
   throw new InvalidArgumentException("Image file $file is not readable");
}
```

This happens with a random selection of images, but if it happens, it continues to happen with that image, so it's not totally random.  If I open the image in Paint and save it with a different name, it works.  It is unrelated to image size, as I've had this error with an image of only 14 kb.

Does anyone have any idea what is wrong?

For example:

[image: This Image does NOT work]

The image above doesn't work, but the one below does.

[image: This image works.]

Comment: The exception message `'Image file C:\inetpub\wwwroot is not readable'` implies that the variable `$file` doesn't include the full filename as intended. Since `$file` is part of that message, you should see an image name like `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\image.png` instead of just `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` there...

Comment: Debug with `var_dump($file)` (or whatever you call the variable which gets passed into the constructor `new ImageManipulator($file)`

Comment: Michael.  I see what you are saying about the `$file` variable.  The thing that confuses me is that renaming the image doesn't solve the problem, but opening it in paint and than saving it does.  This leads me to think that there is something wrong with the images (it happens with about 20% of the images we get).  I'd like to be able to detect what is wrong and fix it on the fly.

Comment: Post some of your PHP implementation code and some examples of the filenames which are faulty. It may be path related, or OS-specific (though fs functions like `is_file()` are tolerant)

Comment: Also, determine which of the tests fails by removing one `is_file($file)` and `is_readable($file)`

Comment: So, I found another file that it doesn't work for.  It's a pic directly from a camera.  In Explorer I get the error noted above.  In Chrome and Firefox, it uses the previously uploaded photo instead.  Also, I separated out the error message and it passed `(!(is_readable($file)))` and failed on  `if (!(is_file($file)))`.  The last file that failed was DSC_0590.JPG , a 3008x2000 pixel image of about 2.39 mb.  I opened it in paint and saved as the same filename in a different directory and it worked.

Comment: You are certain the problem occurs with smaller images? When you saved it with Paint, what was the resultant file size? If Paint added additional jpeg compression and the filesize was reduced that could make a difference. A common default value for upload_max_filesize is only 2M, so your 2.39M file would not be allowed. Check your settings in php.ini for [upload_max_filesize](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize)

Comment: It looks like the size issue. Check the size of the both images the one that you took from camera and the one you saved it using paint.

Comment: I dealt with the size issue long ago by increasing the limit to over 10 meg.  The problem was the case of the file extensions, as I discovered and noted below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help in pointing me in the correct direction.  It turns out that all of the files that failed had upper case extensions (.JPG) and the ones that worked had lowercase extension (.jpg).  Whenever I edited a file in paint, it saved it with a lowercase extension.  Somewhere in the code I was screening for acceptable extensions using an array and the array contained lower case extensions only.  I added a `strtolower` to the comparison and it seems to be working.  Solution:

`// array of valid extensions
    $validExtensions = array('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.png');
    // get extension of the uploaded file
    $fileExtension = strtolower(strrchr($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'], "."));`

```
                     ^^^^^^^^^
```